# When should I use Satellite Assemblies when it comes to localization? And When should I use Resources Files(.resx)?

Tags: c#, localization, resx, satellite-assembly

I'm creating a windows appplication in which I wanna do some localization. That application will also use a DLL that might use a different language(CultureInfo) than the main application.  Which one of those two localization concepts applies best to my case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite think you understand .Net's localization model.
Actually, when you add resx file to your project in Visual Studio and set language (change from Default to something else), not only it will automatically create language copy of your Default (invariant) resource file, but will also create Resource Managers to load data from **Satellite Assemblies** behind the scenes. Go ahead and try it by yourself. You should observe some language-based subdirectories with satellite assemblies in your output directory.

Therefore your question quite does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this concept.  I'll try it!